# When plotting two datasets and one of them has much more data, how do we "normalize" them so they're equal in representation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, dataset

I'm using Plotly to plot some sentiment data yet I have the issue that one character has much more lines than the other so it seems that we cannot compare the two. I'm unsure how to describe for this to find the solution so I hoped that perhaps someone will understand what I'm referring to. Here are images:

[image]

[image]

We cannot really compare orange's negativity with blue's negativity, or can we? Should we have the orange have 600 as the label, it being much smaller than blue or is this correctly scaled?

I'd like this so we can say that for example, blue is less positive than orange.

I'm sorry for any confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Would you consider using percentage or any other ratio of the total lines each character gets ?

Comment: Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which objects you are manipulating, but I read pandas in your tags so I assumed it was a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
# Your data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"orange": [55, 149, 111], "blue": [188, 652, 320]},
                        orient="index", columns=["negative", "neutral", "positive"])
```

| index | negative | neutral | positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 55 | 149 | 111 |
| blue | 188 | 652 | 320 |

You can simply compute the percentage of each value along its row:

```
perc_df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100
```

| index | negative | neutral | positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 17.460317 | 47.301587 | 35.238095 |
| blue | 16.206897 | 56.206897 | 27.586207 |

Once you plot this new DataFrame, the bar heights will be comparable. Percentages are intuitive and widely understood.